# Get a c++ object in QML and use it in javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, qml, qt-quick

I'm making an application in which I'd like to call a function from QML in C++ source, and that c++ function to return me and object which I can use it with the same properties in the javascript part of QML. I've made the connection and everything. I've tried to send a QVariantMap and tried to use that object in javascript, but I don't get the properties of that object

Comment: So at this stage your QML recognizes the c++ objects, correct? Did you create read and write functions for the elements you want to access?

Comment: I have something like this, this c++ method to return a qvariant map

`QVariantMap Mediator::initialize()
{
    vector<Node*> table;
    Mediator m;
    Node TestNode("1", table);
    QVariant test = QVariant::fromValue(TestNode);
    QVariantMap map;
    map.insert("1",proba);
    return map;
}`

and later in the javascript source I have:

`function foo(anObject)
{
   console.log(anObject.getId());
}`

So I want to call a methods from that object. So far if I try to access the map it only prints "QVariant(Node)" 
Sorry for the unformatted text

Comment: Are you sure the object is returned correctly? I personally haven't seen any samples with functions returning object instances (I could be wrong). 

Also I believe any objects exposed to qml need to inherit from QDeclarativeItem and registered with qml... 

Finally, if it all works ok and you get the correct instance back I would expect to get the object's id via the id property : anObject.id (not the underlying getter function)

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways for exporting QObject based types from C++ to QML:

1. Return standalone QObject directly from property READer or Q_INVOKABLE function. Note, object returned as a property has C++ ownership, Q_INVOKABLE-object has JS ownership. You can change this default behaviour via http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdeclarativeengine.html#setObjectOwnership.
2. Return array of QObjects. In that case you should use QObjectList, QDeclarativePropertyMap (not QVariantMap) or QAbstractListModel.

Answer (score 1):

Your classes to be exposed have to inherit from QObject (or QDeclarativeItem if they are UI components) and you will have to register their types in your main() or in a Qt plugin before loading the QML code.

Have a look at http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.7/declarative-tutorials-extending-chapter1-basics.html

Answer (score 0):

To pass an object from C++ to QML as a function return value, the return value type needs to be `QVariant`, not `QVariantMap`, even though that is the type in the C++ code. So just change your `initialize` function signature to

```
QVariant initialize();
```

without changing anything else, and then you can access the properties.

Regarding your later comment on wanting to call methods on that returned object, that is not possible; the returned object is just a set of name-value pairs. If you want the object to have, say, an `id` property, you need to `insert` a value with that key to the `QVariantMap` in C++ before returning it.